# How to create same functionality like gallery view. I used galleryview but it is deprecated

Tags: android, animation

I also used view pager with page container but I want only one side scrolling in circular way.
how to stop left to right scrolling or any other option.

Answer (score 0):

set `setOnPageChangeListener` to your ViewPager

and in

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    if(lastPage>arg0)
      {//User Move to left}
    else(lastPage<arg0) 
     {//User Move to right}
      lastPage=arg0
}
```